# Is it possible to use inline_create with pivot fields with Laravel Backpack?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Is it possible to use Laravel Backpack relationship field type with **both** inline_create and pivot fields enabled?

I'm trying to make this happen:

I have 2 entities, Products and Productions, and both have a belongsToMany relation defined in the model. Therefore they have a pivot table with product_id and production_id.
In this pivot table I have a count column.

With Backpack I'm trying to solve the following:
I want to fetch products on productions create operation, or create product from this view and specify the pivot field count with it.

If I remove the 'subfields' property from the field definition, the add field button shows up.

I've attached 3 screenshots of the mentioned functionality.

[Product with Add, but without count field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vB5p.png)

[Clicked on "Add" - Modal opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB3OF.png)

[Product with count pivot field and without Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIbRS.png)

Answer (score 2):

Hello @roamingTurkey !

You should be able to do it, but you need to configure your `pivotSelect` key in your n-n field definition : https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-how-to#extra-saving-additional-attributes-to-the-pivot-table

Let me know!